# Why is $\Sigma^*$ concatenated with some language regular?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages

Let $\Sigma=\{a,b\}$. Why is the concatenation of any language with $\Sigma^*$ always regular? I found a problem where $(a+b)^*$concatenated with $a^nb^n$ was regular?

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just hand you the solution; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/1284/98) for tips on asking questions about exercise problems. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]?

Comment: Who claims that? I'm not sure it is true, but either way, a hint: Use the Myhill-Nerode criterion.

Comment: The claim is false. The language $a^{n^2} b \Sigma^*$ isn't regular.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus That should probably be posted as an answer. (It fully resolves the question, even though it's not what the asker was looking for.)

Comment: I suspect soon the question will be changed to reflect this new information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The claim is false. For example, if you concatenate $\{ a^{n^2} b : n \geq 0\}$ and $\Sigma^*$ then you get a non-regular language (exercise).

In contrast, the concatenation of $\{ a^n b^n : n \geq 0 \}$ and $(a+b)^*$ is regular, since it equals the latter; this is the case whenever the former language contains the empty word.

Finally, the concatenation of $\{ a^n b^n : n \geq 1 \}$ and $(a+b)^*$ is again not regular, since intersecting it with $a^*b^*$ gives the non-regular language $ \{ a^n b^m : m \geq n \geq 1 \} $.